# Complex database design for many checkboxes

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm currently creating a website for a local hospital. The problem I am currently facing: The website has too many checkboxes and fields that are enabled/disabled depending on the checkbox.

This is url to the website: http://ali.ezyro.com/adan/myForm.php

Since I have little experience with databases, what is the best way to design the database to hold all the data of this document?

Comment: I think the best way you should divide it by part, 1 part = 1 table.

Comment: 1) Design a table to store patient information ex. Patient. 2) Design a separate table for each block you have. 3) Keep foreign key of table Patient in all other table created in step 2. 4) If you don't want to keep Patient key in other table then you can create relation between them as well. 5) If you preferring step 4 then patient key must be there in at least one of the table created in step 2

Answer (score -1):

This is a case where a relational database may not be your best option - it all depends on how the data is used within the system.

The straightforward option is to design one (very wide) table for each patient. Each attribute is modelled as a column; multi-valued attributes (check boxes) have one column for each valid option, single-valued attribute which require a lookup from a list of valid options use a foreign key to a table holding the valid lookups (e.g. in the patient table, you have a column called `cervical_collar_id`, and you have a separate table called `cervical_collar_values` with `1 - prehospital, 2-on arrival, 3-not required`).

This allows you to store the data, and query it efficiently using standard SQL (find all patients who arrived with a prehospital cervical collar, for instance). 
The "if you select box x, then box y becomes mandatory" logic should probably live in the application, not your schema.

But this is a difficult design to work with - adding attributes to the patient record is non-trivial. Wide tables are usually a bad sign.

You might decide that's a bad thing, and go for "entity/attribute/value" design. Lots of Stack Overflow answers will tell you the benefits and drawbacks of this - Google is your friend. TL;DR: even moderately complex queries become almost impossible.

You might instead decide to store the data as a document - most database engines store JSON and XML, and allow you to query this data efficiently. It has the benefit of being easier to develop, and easier to change - but you lose the built-in validation that the relational model gives you.